# How to prevent an osmnx figure from being shown in Python (jupyter)

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-lab, osmnx

Using `matplotlib` we can prevent a figure from being shown using the `close` function

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = range(0,5)
b = range(0,10,2)

plt.plot(a,b, 'r-*')

plt.close()
```

Because `osmnx` uses `matplotlib` in background, I though the `close` function could have been used in the same way

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import osmnx as ox

graph = ox.graph_from_bbox(41.97278, 41.97614,  -87.73993, -87.73755, network_type='drive')

ox.plot_graph(graph, 
             bbox=[41.97278, 41.97614,  -87.73993, -87.73755], 
              )
plt.close()
```

Unfortunately the figure is still displayed.
Is there a way to prevent the figure from being shown ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the OSMnx [documentation](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.plot.plot_graph) for that function?

> **show (bool)** – if True, call pyplot.show() to show the figure
>
> **close (bool)** – if True, call pyplot.close() to close the figure

The use of these parameters are also demonstrated in the OSMnx usage [examples](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples).

```py
import osmnx as ox
bbox = 41.97278, 41.97614,  -87.73993, -87.73755
G = ox.graph_from_bbox(*bbox, network_type='drive')
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, bbox=bbox, show=False, close=True)
```

Comment: Thank you @gboeing. I have missed that parameter